# Transformation on hash to csv in custom format in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hash

I want to convert hash to csv with custom format in Ruby on Rails.

Input hash:

```
 [{"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 00:00", "Price"=>"14"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 01:00", "Price"=>"13"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 02:00", "Price"=>"14"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 03:00", "Price"=>"19"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 04:00", "Price"=>"28"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 05:00", "Price"=>"24"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-18", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-18 06:00", "Price"=>"21"}, 
 {"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 00:00", "Price"=>"16"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 01:00", "Price"=>"10"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 02:00", "Price"=>"11"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 03:00", "Price"=>"14"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 04:00", "Price"=>"26"}, {"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 05:00", "Price"=>"22"},
{"Date"=>"2019-03-19", "Date Hour"=>"2019-03-19 06:00", "Price"=>"25"}
```

Expected Output:

```
Date,Date Hour,Mar-18,Mar-19
2019-01-01,00:00,14,16
2019-01-01,01:00,13,10
2019-01-01,02:00,14,11
2019-01-01,03:00,19,14
2019-01-01,04:00,28,26
2019-01-01,05:00,24,22
2019-01-01,06:00,21,25
```

Currently input hash has 2 dates, it may contains multiple date values. Based on the above input, I want to build the csv with above expected output?

How can I get the above expected output?

Update: Here is my code. But my code only works for single day of data. How can I enhance it if its for multiple days of data in input csv?

```
# Convert csv to hash
 rows = CSV.parse(response, headers: true).map(&:to_h)

# Add transformation in hash
    rows.each do |hash|
      # Remove Hour from Date Hour values
      hash["Date Hour"] = hash["Date Hour"].gsub!(hash["Date"], "").strip
      # Replace Price column name with date value (e.g Mar-19)
      hash[Date.parse(hash["Date"]).strftime("%b-%d")] = hash.delete("Price")
      # Set static Date
      hash["Date"] = "2019-01-01"
    end

# Convert hash to csv

    # Extract column names from first row of data
    column_names = rows.first.keys
    # Generate CSV after transformation of csv
    csv_response = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      rows.each do |row|
        # Extract values for row of data
        csv << row.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Please show what you have already tried. SO is not a service to write the code for you for free.

Comment: Also, it’s unclear why the expected output has the date `Jan 1, 2019`, where hours come from. Also, your input is an invalid ruby.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I have updated the question. Kindly take a look. Jan 1, 2019 is a static date value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First transform your input:

```
result =
  input.group_by do |hash|
    hash["Date Hour"].split.last
  end.values.map do |arr|
    arr.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
      acc["Date"] ||= "2019-01-01"
      acc["Date Hour"] ||= h["Date Hour"].split.last
      acc[Date.iso8601(h["Date"]).strftime('%b-%d')] = h["Price"]
    end
  end

#⇒ [{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"00:00", "Mar-18"=>"14", "Mar-19"=>"16"},
#   {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"01:00", "Mar-18"=>"13", "Mar-19"=>"10"},
#   {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"02:00", "Mar-18"=>"14", "Mar-19"=>"11"},
#   {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"03:00", "Mar-18"=>"19", "Mar-19"=>"14"},
#   {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"04:00", "Mar-18"=>"28", "Mar-19"=>"26"},
#   {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"05:00", "Mar-18"=>"24", "Mar-19"=>"22"},
#   {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Date Hour"=>"06:00", "Mar-18"=>"21", "Mar-19"=>"25"}]
```

Now just spit it out to CSV.

---

Shameless plug: one might use [`SeeAsVee`](https://github.com/am-kantox/see_as_vee) gem to produce a CSV file out of an array of hashes:

```
require 'see_as_vee'
SeeAsVee.csv result
#⇒ #<File:/tmp/am/see_as_vee20190320-10403-ub0p5y.csv>
```

Comment: Which variable has the final result? I don't see an expected output when I print input variable?

Comment: The result was returned by a clause I posted. I expected you to be able to assign it to the variable yourself. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I am able to get the result now.